# android のテーブルレイアウトの動的作成｡

Tags: android, java, android-layout

androidアプリで､TableRowを動的に作成しようと思い､次のコードを書いたのですが､何故かpositionの列だけ表示されません｡

```
//main.class
ViewGroup vg = (ViewGroup)findViewById(R.id.tb_finish);
    for(int i=0; i<globals.numPlayer; i++){
        //行の追加
        getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.table_row_3, vg);
        //文字設定
        TableRow tr = (TableRow)vg.getChildAt(i);
        //名前の列
        String name;
        //役職
        String position;
        //存在するか
        String isAlive;

        //設定
        name = globals.pList.get(i).name;
        position = globals.pList.get(i).getPosition(FinishActivity.this);
        if(globals.pList.get(i).isAlive==true){
            isAlive = getString(R.string.alive);
        }else{
            isAlive = getString(R.string.dead);
        }

        ((TextView)(tr.getChildAt(0))).setText(name);
        ((TextView)(tr.getChildAt(1))).setText(position);
        ((TextView)(tr.getChildAt(2))).setText(isAlive);
    }
```

以下はレイアウトXMLです｡

```
//main.xml
<TableLayout 
        android:id="@+id/tb_finish"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:collapseColumns="1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tv_wincamp">

</TableLayout>

//table_row_3
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableRow xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

<TextView 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

<TextView 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

<TextView 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</TableRow>
```

以下が`getPosition()`です｡

```
    public String getPosition(Context context){
    switch (this.position) {
    case 0:
        return context.getString(R.string.civilian);
    case 1:
        return context.getString(R.string.diviner);
    case 2:
        return context.getString(R.string.mystic);
    case 3:
        return context.getString(R.string.knight);
    case 4:
        return context.getString(R.string.freemason);
    case 5:
        return context.getString(R.string.monstercat);
    case 6:
        return context.getString(R.string.werewolf);
    case 7:
        return context.getString(R.string.fanatic);
    case 8:
        return context.getString(R.string.vampire);
    default:
        return "hoge";

    }
```

このメソッドは`Player`というクラスのメソッドです｡  `Player`はActivityを継承していません｡

Comment: 「globals.pList.get(i).getPosition(FinishActivity.this);」にある `getPosition()` メソッドの定義を追記していただけますか？

Comment: `getPosition()`のメソッド定義を追記しました｡ あと､この`main.class`と言うのは`FinishActivity`のことです｡すみません｡

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`android:collapseColumns=1`のためです。

指定された列は折りたたまれ、非表示となります。0始端ですので1を指定すると、`position`の列が非表示になります。

Comment: 返答ありがとうございます｡  無事解決出来ました｡